# How to verify if a shell script variable is alphanumeric?

Tags: shell-script

I would like to check if a shell script variable has only alphabetical and numeric characters:

```
str1="3dr>f43fe*" --> Not good
str2="RFEfew3"    --> Good
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What did you try so far? Look the documentation of `echo` and `grep`

Answer (score 2):

To lay out the comment of Ángel, the following works, using `grep`:

```sh
echo "$str" | grep -q '^[[:alnum:]]*$' && echo Good
```

- The used regex matches any string that consists between its start `^` and end `$` of any number `*` of alphanumerical characters `[[:alnum:]]`, defined here via newer [character classes syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes).

Older versions of `grep` might not yet support those double square bracket regex, in which case you can use this alternative:

```sh
echo "$str" | grep -q '^[A-Za-z0-9]*$' && echo Good
```

- Alphanumerical characters are matched here via character ranges, which are generally still better supported throughout especially older tools/versions.
- **NB: While in most cases character range and character class definitions lead to the same result, there are differences with special characters of certain languages. E.g. French `ç` `æ` `œ` or Polish `ą` usually do not match `[a-z]`, but may or may not match `[[:alnum:]]` if the related system locale (language) has been set. To be 100% sure `export` or prefix `grep` with e.g. `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` to get a consistent result on all systems. *Many thanks to Kamil Maciorowski for this important hint.***

In the above two cases, an empty variables matches as well. If at least one character should be present, use:

```sh
echo "$str" | grep -qE '^[[:alnum:]]+$' && echo Good
```

- The `+` stands for "at least once", compared to `*` which allows "zero times" as well. But since the `+` is part the extended regex syntax, most `grep` builds require the `-E` flag.

The `-q` option makes `grep` returning the exit code silently, so you can use if-then-else, `&&` and/or `||` to proceed based on the result.

---

The above solutions assume that `$str` is a single-line variable. If it contains of multiple lines, only one line needs to match, while the other lines could contain other characters without effecting the `grep` exit code.

If a multi-line variable should be ruled out, `bash` conditionals allow to do:

```bsh
[[ $str =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]] && echo Good
```

On all POSIX shells (i.e. `sh`), `expr` can be used:

```sh
expr match "$str" "^[[:alnum:]]\+$" > /dev/null && echo Good
```

- In `expr`, to use extended regex syntax `+`, it needs to be escaped with a leading backslash `\+`. Basic regex syntax, like `*`, works with that. But `^[[:alnum:]]*$` for some reason does not match the empty string, not sure why.
- I added `> /dev/null` to redirect the standard output (STDOUT) to the `/dev/null` Nirvana, since `expr` otherwise prints the amount of matched characters or a `0` if it does not match. Probably this is the reason why the empty string never returns "true", as zero characters matched.

Comment: Can you describe the regex you are using?

Comment: I added regex explanations as well as a way to exclude empty string and multi-line matches.

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9]` is *not* equivalent to `[[:alnum:]]`. The former depends on `LC_COLLATE`. In some locales [`[a-z]` includes `B`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19322/108618), in others it doesn't. Sorting order also depends on `LC_COLLATE` but [in a different way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578053/108618). `[[:alnum:]]` depends on `LC_TYPE`. Even if the two variables are equal there is no equivalency. In my Debian 10 the locale is `pl_PL.UTF-8`. `sort` sorts `a`, `ą`, `b`; still `[a-z]` does not include `ą`. `[A-Za-z0-9]` does not include `ą` but `[[:alnum:]]` does. This is complicated.

Comment: Many thanks for this important hint. I added the hint + the idea to set the locale, if a consistent result across systems is needed. The a > A > b range/sorting is disturbing in general and may have lead to a huge amount of hard to debug bugs already, but at least in this particular case it doesn't play a role since all lower-case and upper-case characters are to be matched anyway, which is true in both cases.